# Disable mouse EventListener when hovering a Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mouseevent, addeventlistener, event-listener

I added 2 EventListener(s) in order to control the scroll and have it fluid and smooth on Chrome (especially), which by default has a horrible behavior.

```
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

var time = 1300;
var distance = 270;

function wheel(event) {
    if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
    else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

    handle();
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
}

function handle() {

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - (distance * delta)
    }, time);
}


$(document).keydown(function (e) {

    switch (e.which) {
        //up
        case 38:
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - distance
            }, time);
            break;

            //down
        case 40:
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + distance
            }, time);
            break;
    }
});
```

Everything's working perfectly except that I need to add a Google Maps API v3 map. And it has another EventListener that zooms in and out when mouse is hovering the map and you use the mouse wheel. How can I disable my script when mouse is hovering the map? Here's the link the my page (you can see the behavior), live: http://www.rendezvousroma.it/new/contatti.php

Comment: set the `scrollwheel`-property of the map to `false`

Comment: But I'd like to use it. Isn't it possible to disable "my" script just when hovering the map?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly)

For me your script doesn't work at all when the mouse is over the map. When I use the mousewheel over the map the map will be zoomed but the page doesn't scroll(I guess that's the desired behaviour)

There is only the queue of the currently running animation that will scroll the page  when you are over the map. When this is what you want to avoid, observe the `mouseover`-event of the map and stop the animation:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(map,'mouseover',function(e){
    $('html, body').stop();
  });
```

To prevent the page from scrolling in Firefox add this too:

```
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(map.getDiv(),'DOMMouseScroll',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

It should prevent the event from bubbling up to the document.

Comment: Well, that's exactly the problem I face (at least in Firefox). When I'm hover the map and use the mouse wheel map's zoom is activated and page scrolls. I'll try the snippet soon :)

Comment: It's really strange! I tried with Internet Explorer and it doesn't happen. With Firefox instead it does.. try visiting the link at the question... :(

Comment: I updated the page (http://www.rendezvousroma.it/new/contatti.php) with the second snippet but Firefox is still an ass .. :P

EDIT: I added the snippets out the G Maps function cause if I add 'em right above google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); the map isn't loaded anymore

Comment: add the snippets right after the statement where you create the `google.maps.Map`.

Answer (score 0):

Put this on the div: `style="user-select: none; pointer-events: none;"`